# Why is int 9 greater than int 9?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a simple function to take a string, convert it to a list of numbers and print out the highest value. Could someone please tell me why 9 is bigger than 10? As the function compares two int's I cant figure out whats wrong. When row 4 executes it says <class 'int'>.

```
def findMax(numbers):
    toSort = [int(c) for c in numbers.split(" ")]
    print(toSort)
    print(type(toSort[0]))
    max = numbers[0]
    for number in numbers:
        if number > max:
            max = number
    return max


numbers = "1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9 10"

print(findMax(numbers))
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The string "9" is greater than the string "10" because strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: You should be using`toSort` instead of `numbers` throughout the function

Comment: You are actually comparing the individual _characters_ in the string  `"1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9 10"` against each other, and `"9"` lexicographically sorts after all the other digit characters and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing integers, you're comparing strings. Strings are compared lexicographically, i.e. dictionary order.

Consider

```
if int(number) > max:
  max = int(number)
```